# Trigger enter key

Tags: jquery, json

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<title>Nutrition-Dossier</title>

<style type="text/css">
    h1 {
        text-align: center;
        color: #000080;
        font-size: 60;
    }

        table, th, td 
        {
            margin:10px 0;
            border:solid 1px #333;
            padding:2px 4px;
            font:15px Verdana;
        }
        th {
            font-weight:bold;
        }

        table 
{ 
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}


table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 5px;
  background: #3090C7 url("gradient.gif") bottom left repeat-x;
  color: ;
}

td, th {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

  .btnGetNutrition  {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 39px 0px -24px #e67a73;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 39px 0px -24px #e67a73;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 39px 0px -24px #e67a73;
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #e4685d), color-stop(1, #eb675e));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #e4685d 5%, #eb675e 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e4685d 5%, #eb675e 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #e4685d 5%, #eb675e 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #e4685d 5%, #eb675e 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #e4685d 5%, #eb675e 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#e4685d', endColorstr='#eb675e',GradientType=0);
    background-color:#e4685d;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    border-radius:4px;
    border:1px solid #ffffff;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:italic;
    padding:6px 15px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 6px #b23e35;
}
.btnGetNutrition :hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #eb675e), color-stop(1, #e4685d));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #eb675e 5%, #e4685d 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eb675e 5%, #e4685d 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #eb675e 5%, #e4685d 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #eb675e 5%, #e4685d 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #eb675e 5%, #e4685d 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#eb675e', endColorstr='#e4685d',GradientType=0);
    background-color:#eb675e;
}
.myButton:active {
    position:relative;
    top:2px;
}


</style>




<style style="text/css">
body {
  background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSmt8Kp8jgPmMTCzmLaYXCYlkl-cPGC7gwcnPpaBtPADHrAq2YirQ");
  background-size: 1350px 700px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
</style> 

</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>




<h1><blink>NUTRITION DOSSIER</blink></h1>

 <form>

    <center><font face="verdana" size="03" style="color:darkGreen" text="bold">Enter Food keyword: <input type="text" name="food" id="txtFood"></b></center><br /></font>
  <center><button id= "btnGetNutrition"  class= btnGetNutrition type="button" value = 'Get Nutrition Data'>Get Food Details</button></center><br/><br/>

   <center><font face="verdana" size= "03" color="Brown">Search Results are below:</font></center>




   <div id="resultDiv">
   </div>
    <br/>

    </form> 




<script>



$('#btnGetNutrition').click(function () {
      var resultElement = $('#resultDiv');
      resultElement.html('');

      $('#txtFood').keypress(function (e) {
          var key = e.which;
          if(key == 13)  // the enter key code
           {
             $('input[name = btnGetNutrition]').click();
             return false;  
           }
         });

      var requestData = $('#txtFood').val();


             if(requestData=='')
       {
                   alert('Enter a valid food keyword to obtain Nutrition Dossier');
       }



      var nutrientDataUrl;
      var NutrientData;
      var foodDataUrl = 'https://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/search/?format=json&q=' + requestData + '&sort=n&max=01&offset=0&api_key=xahKL10HPCqKkmh8B9Xai5UUbcHSx8ihvgoUhWuX';
      var foodData; 


      $.getJSON(foodDataUrl, function(data) {
        foodData = data;

      }).then(function() {
    nutrientDataUrl = 'https://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/nutrients/?format=json&api_key=xahKL10HPCqKkmh8B9Xai5UUbcHSx8ihvgoUhWuX&nutrients=205&nutrients=204&nutrients=208&nutrients=269&ndbno=' + foodData.list.item[0].ndbno;

        $.getJSON(nutrientDataUrl, function(data) {
          NutrientData = data;
        }).then(function() {

          $('#resultDiv').append('<table><caption>' + NutrientData.report.foods[0].name + '</caption><tr><th>Nutrient</th><th>Unit</th><th>Value</th></tr>');


           NutrientData.report.foods[0].nutrients.forEach(function(item, index){

                   $('#resultDiv table').append('<tr><td>' + item.nutrient + '</td><td>' + item.unit + '</td><td>' + item.value + '</td></tr>');
          }) 
          $('#resultDiv table').append('</table>');

        }).fail(function() {
            alert('failed');
        });
      });
      });

</script>


</body>
</html>


    enter code here
```

on hitting enter the site should do the same as clicking the button.

When i click enter button,it should display data without tap key from the keyboard.

At present data is appearing if i hit the  tab and then enter.So, i want that functionality in my program.

Also,i want to utilize this source code [ as to upload in websites]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `$('input[name=btnGetNutrition]').click();` but you should use `$('input[id=btnGetNutrition]').click();`

Since your button has an `id` and not a `name`

`<button id="btnGetNutrition" class="btnGetNutrition" type="button" value='Get Nutrition Data'>Get Food Details</button>`

You also have `$('#txtFood').keypress(function(e)` inside `$('#btnGetNutrition').click(function(e) {`.  Move `$('#txtFood').keypress` out of it.

I've added `console.log("click trigger")` inside the click function so you can see it triggers on enter keypress

**Working example**

```js
$('#txtFood').keypress(function(e) {
  var key = e.which;
  if (key == 13) // the enter key code
  {
    console.log(key)
    $('#btnGetNutrition').trigger("click");
    return false;
  }
});
$('#btnGetNutrition').click(function(e) {
  console.log("click trigger")
  var resultElement = $('#resultDiv');
  resultElement.html('');



  var requestData = $('#txtFood').val();


  if (requestData == '') {
    alert('Enter a valid food keyword to obtain Nutrition Dossier');
  }



  var nutrientDataUrl;
  var NutrientData;
  var foodDataUrl = 'https://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/search/?format=json&q=' + requestData + '&sort=n&max=01&offset=0&api_key=xahKL10HPCqKkmh8B9Xai5UUbcHSx8ihvgoUhWuX';
  var foodData;


  $.getJSON(foodDataUrl, function(data) {
    foodData = data;

  }).then(function() {
    nutrientDataUrl = 'https://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/nutrients/?format=json&api_key=xahKL10HPCqKkmh8B9Xai5UUbcHSx8ihvgoUhWuX&nutrients=205&nutrients=204&nutrients=208&nutrients=269&ndbno=' + foodData.list.item[0].ndbno;

    $.getJSON(nutrientDataUrl, function(data) {
      NutrientData = data;
    }).then(function() {

      $('#resultDiv').append('<table><caption>' + NutrientData.report.foods[0].name + '</caption><tr><th>Nutrient</th><th>Unit</th><th>Value</th></tr>');


      NutrientData.report.foods[0].nutrients.forEach(function(item, index) {

        $('#resultDiv table').append('<tr><td>' + item.nutrient + '</td><td>' + item.unit + '</td><td>' + item.value + '</td></tr>');
      })
      $('#resultDiv table').append('</table>');

    }).fail(function() {
      alert('failed');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #000080;
  font-size: 60;
}

table,
th,
td {
  margin: 10px 0;
  border: solid 1px #333;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  font: 15px Verdana;
}

th {
  font-weight: bold;
}

table {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 5px;
  background: #3090C7 url("gradient.gif") bottom left repeat-x;
  color: ;
}

td,
th {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

.btnGetNutrition {
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 39px 0px -24px #e67a73;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 39px 0px -24px #e67a73;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 39px 0px -24px #e67a73;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #e4685d), color-stop(1, #eb675e));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #e4685d 5%, #eb675e 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e4685d 5%, #eb675e 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #e4685d 5%, #eb675e 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #e4685d 5%, #eb675e 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #e4685d 5%, #eb675e 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#e4685d', endColorstr='#eb675e', GradientType=0);
  background-color: #e4685d;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  padding: 6px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 6px #b23e35;
}

.btnGetNutrition :hover {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #eb675e), color-stop(1, #e4685d));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eb675e 5%, #e4685d 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eb675e 5%, #e4685d 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eb675e 5%, #e4685d 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #eb675e 5%, #e4685d 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eb675e 5%, #e4685d 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#eb675e', endColorstr='#e4685d', GradientType=0);
  background-color: #eb675e;
}

.myButton:active {
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
}

body {
  background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSmt8Kp8jgPmMTCzmLaYXCYlkl-cPGC7gwcnPpaBtPADHrAq2YirQ");
  background-size: 1350px 700px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>
  <blink>NUTRITION DOSSIER</blink>
</h1>
<form>
<center>
  <font face="verdana" size="03" style="color:darkGreen" text="bold">Enter Food keyword: <input type="text" name="food" id="txtFood"></b>
</center><br /></font>
<center><button id="btnGetNutrition" class=b tnGetNutrition type="button" value='Get Nutrition Data'>Get Food Details</button></center><br/><br/>

<center>
  <font face="verdana" size="03" color="Brown">Search Results are below:</font>
</center>

</form>


<div id="resultDiv">
</div>
<br/>
```

Comment: Thanks Gentleman.Can you help me out 'if the user types 'A' then all words related to 'A' would appear as it comes in 'GOOGLE' ENGINE.This is in the same context.

Answer (score 0):

move your logic into seperate function(lets be getFoodDetails). call it in click event and keypress event:

```
$('#btnGetNutrition').click(function () {
    getFoodDetails();
});

$('#txtFood').on("keypress", function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {      
    getFoodDetails();            
    return false; 
    }
});

Note: remove this code $('input[name = btnGetNutrition]').click();
```